# any example shows that coloring number does not equal to clique number?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Could you please show me any graph whose coloring number does not equal to its clique number ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

As often, the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) works.

Comment: The 5-cycle is probably the minimal example, but Petersen's is my go-to example to check.